# Why is iPhone iOS showing invalid date for momentjs

Tags: javascript, ios, time, safari, momentjs

I have a datepicker which was returning a moment object that was always in UTC timezone. I needed to do some logic on this date, but always wanted it in the users local timezone so I did the following:

```
    //strip submission date of timezone offset
    let submission_date = moment(this.state.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a');
    submission_date = moment(submission_date);
    let last_date = this.last_date.diff(submission_date, 'days');
```

However, when I do this my iPhone complains that `submission_date` is not a valid date. Desktop is fine so I'm guessing this is a safari issue. When I inspect `this.state.startDate` just prior to being momentized it's a string like `2018-11-01T17:52:44-00:00`

Shouldn't moment accept that as a valid date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had figured out that it's the `a` flag in the format string. I changed it to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` and it worked perfectly. Safari must not like `am`/`pm` data.

Comment: I'm using YYYY-MM-DD and still getting invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping up with String function

```
//strip submission date of timezone offset
let submission_date = moment(String(this.state.startDate),'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a');
let last_date = moment(String(this.last_date),'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a').diff(submission_date, 'days');
```

Safari engine has some unique way of processing/parsing the date object

Answer (score 0):

follow this format. year should be at the beginning. have to use "/" instead of "-".
cannot use "MMM" for month

```
YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm A
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by ensuring all the letters in my ISO8601 formatted date-time (such as T and Z) were upper case. When they were lower case, moment failed to parse the date-time string.